# AzureIoTUtility Cocoapods Installation Failed

Tags: cocoapods, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to install the azure libraries via cocoapods for device use but it's not letting me. The branch `jbobotek-test-cocoa` is missing.

Below are the console log when trying to do a `pod install`:

```
Installing AzureIoTUtility (1.1.12d)

[!] Error installing AzureIoTUtility
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility.git /var/folders/f9/zvsz4k2j56d35r49dq33cc0r0000gp/T/d20200117-31514-hwmiqr --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch jbobotek-test-cocoa

Cloning into '/var/folders/f9/zvsz4k2j56d35r49dq33cc0r0000gp/T/d20200117-31514-hwmiqr'...
warning: Could not find remote branch jbobotek-test-cocoa to clone.
fatal: Remote branch jbobotek-test-cocoa not found in upstream origin
```

Comment: Can you please try to use version 1.1.11 (`pod 'AzureIoTUtility', '= 1.1.11'`) for the moment?

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Issue is now resolved. 1.1.12x branches are now restored.